# Docker terminal on windows 10: does clipboard work?

Tags: windows, docker, clipboard

On windows 10 you can use shortcuts for clipboard
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt427362.aspx

But when I try the combination shift+ins with docker terminal it doesn't seem to paste what I have copied.

Answer (score 0):

What do you mean by "docker terminal"? docker does not provide it's own terminal - it can use any shell you want - windows CMD, Powershell, even mingw64 bash.

The link you provided refers to windows CMD. <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>ins</kbd> works in Windows Command Prompt, but not in Windows Powershell.

For pasting in powershell, use right mouse click or <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>v</kbd>.

Comment: In Docker for windows - when a container is running, you can "click" on a CLI option and it brings up the terminal for the container.

CTRL-V / SHIFT-INS, does not PASTE what you copied to the HOST clipboard